# How to generate a random sentence out of those provided in html?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a generator that provides a sentence after hitting a "generate" button in a text box below. Similar to a random number generator, but with sentences. I have been trying to figure this out, and then resulted to this!

HTML

Comment: Just HTML? It probably is not possible without javascript. And you should have an array of things, not just random things. It works with numbers, not with words.

Comment: not getting it, what is this mean?

Comment: You're really going to have to clarify what you want here. (1) Where are you storing your sentences? Are they coming from another file, or are they being stored as HTML? (2) As @AstroBoyR noted, you'll likely have to use some JavaScript, not just HTML. (3) It's unclear how you're returning your "randomized" sentences: "...that provides a sentence after hitting a 'generate' button in a text box'..." The button would be **outside** your text box.

Comment: Yes, Javascript would be needed for this.